# Autocomplete in text box to save it to list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, list-form

I have two lists one of the list has the column "Title" with all the data . The other list has the outcome column where i am trying to get the autocomplete of this  first list "Title" column data. I am using Jquery and SPServices to get the data in the outcome column and is working fine. But I want to select the text and save it to the list form .I am unable to succeed in doing so. Can someone suggest me on how to follow the approach on this. Please find the jqeury which I am using to get the autocomplete work to show the data in the outcome column.

```
<script src="/sites/supply/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.min.js" > </script >
<script src="/sites/supply/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" > </script >
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[id ^= 'AutoComplete']").SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "NACISCodes",
            sourceColumn: "Title",
            columnName: "AutoComplete",
            numChars: 2,
            ignoreCase: true,
            slideDownSpeed: fast,
            debug: true
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script works fine in my local.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "NACISCodes",
            sourceColumn: "Title",
            columnName: "AutoComplete",
            numChars: 2,
            ignoreCase: true,
            slideDownSpeed: 100,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting the data but my issue is am unable to select the data and save it to the list form.